# Build errors with a new Swift app

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7

Totally new Swift.  I was going through the tutorial at [RayWenderLich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114173/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-2-your-first-project)
and ran into some build errors before even putting in any code.  I created the new project, click run, and the following errors show up.  (I'm using Xcode 7.3.1)

- IconsCore.h

  - Unknown type name 'IconFamily Resource'
  - Unknown type name 'IconFamilyHandle'
  - Unknown type name 'IconFamilyHandle'
- NSURLError.h

  - Could not build module 'CoreServices'
- ApplicationServices.h

  - Could not build module 'CoreServices'
- Could not build Objective-C module 'Foundation'

My searching is turning up empty and getting quite frustrating.  Especially when I'm just trying to get started.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is IconsCore.h? Is that a file you included in your project? This question doesn't contain very much info about your setup.

Comment: It's not a file I added.  I'm not sure what else to put about my setup.  I have changed nothing from what Xcode gives me when I create a new project.  Could something be wrong with my Xcode install?

Comment: For what platform and with what template did you create the project? Have you written any @import or #imports?

Comment: Ah, OS X > Application > Command Line Tool.  I have not written any @import or #imports.

Comment: Exactly how far into the tutorial are you?

Comment: The part that has the heading "Running Your App" is where the trouble starts.  The playground portion works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm no longer having the problem.  Looking to fix Xcode, I ran a terminal command that cleaned something out of /var/logs, and then I could no longer boot.  So I went scorched earth and reinstalled the entire OS and Xcode.  I did run into some errors while installing, (I think my SSD is failing) but I no longer get the errors while trying to build and run an app.

Summary - I THINK that the problem was a result of corrupted OS or Xcode files.